Simply trying to use opendir() in my program gives me segmentation fault. Im on vscode and in my schools linux sever
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define MAX 100

int copy(char fileName[], char dirName[])
{
    printf("0");
    
    //open directory and test if it opens successfully
    DIR *OGdir = opendir("~/");
    struct dirent *OGdp = readdir(OGdir);

    if(OGdir == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nUnable To Open Directory\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    printf("1\n");
    //more code will go here i have more to do but this wont even work
    return(0);
}


Im opening the current directory, i need to be able to open a file within it to copy it over but i cant even open the directory.
This also happens when I tried just opening the file without trying the directory. I assume it has something to do with the ssh server or something else I need to do but Ive tried so many different things and this is almost exactly how everywhere tells me to do this, am i forgetting something? is there something special I need to do since Im on my schools linux ssh server? this is my first time using ssh servers so i apologize if this is something i should know already.

You should be checking if OGdir is not NULL before dereferencing it, and also opendir() does not understand ~, thus the NULL pointer.

First, you are passing OGdir to readdir before checking if OGdir is not NULL. You should check first before using the pointer at all:
if(OGdir == NULL)
{
    printf("\nUnable To Open Directory\n");
    // return(-1);
    return EXIT_FAILURE; // This a more portable way to indicate failure than the constant -1
}

struct dirent *OGdp = readdir(OGdir); // Move this line after the if

Second, opening a file/directory from code is not compatible with the use of the "~/" notation. If you want to use the current working directory, use opendir("."); instead. Or you could manually query the home directory.
But if you type echo ~ in the Terminal, your home directory is printed, which shows that ~ is expanded to your home directory at the command-line level, rather than at the program level.
Also, typically you do not just call readdir() once. If at some point you want to loop through all files in a directory, I would suggest using:
struct dirent *OGdp;
while((OGdp = readdir(OGDir)) != NULL)
{
    // Your code
}

And not:
struct dirent *OGdp = readdir(OGDir);
while(OGdp != NULL)
{
    // Your code
    OGdp = readdir(OGDir);
}


Another way of explaining it is ~ is interpreted by the shell and expanded to $HOME. (in shells that provide that feature, most do) Also, don't return negative values to the shell. C provides EXIT_SUCCESS (0) AND EXIT_FAILURE (1). See, e.g. POSIX return

use perror instead of printf when describing an error...
